# How to use a php variable in div?

Tags: php, html

How can i use a php variable in div tag? likewise the one $frame1url in frame.

```
<frame src='<?php echo $frame1url ?>' name='RTop' scrolling='auto' />
```

**Any Help?**

the variable was created after the session was already created.

**see updated code below**

```
$pwd_alert_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pwd_expires_date . '-7 days'));

if (strtotime($pwd_alert_date) != '' &&
  strtotime($current_date) >= strtotime($pwd_alert_date) &&
  (!isset($_SESSION['expiration_msg'])
  or $_SESSION['expiration_msg'] == 0)) {
 $is_expired = true;
 $_SESSION['expiration_msg'] = 1; // only show the expired message once
 }
 }

 if ($is_expired) {
 //display the php file containing the password expiration message.
 $frame1url = "pwd_expires_alert.php";
 }
 else if (!empty($_POST['patientID'])) {
 $patientID = 0 + $_POST['patientID'];
 $frame1url = "../patient_file/summary/demographics.php?set_pid=".attr($patientID);
 }
 else if ($GLOBALS['athletic_team']) {
 $frame1url = "../reports/players_report.php?embed=1";
 }
 else if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == "loadcalendar") {
 $frame1url = "calendar/index.php?pid=" . attr($_GET['pid']);
 if (isset($_GET['date'])) $frame1url .= "&date=" . attr($_GET['date']);
 }
else if ($GLOBALS['concurrent_layout']) {
 // new layout
 if ($GLOBALS['default_top_pane']) {
$frame1url=attr($GLOBALS['default_top_pane']);
} else {
$frame1url = "main_info.php";
}
}
else {
// old layout
$frame1url = "main.php?mode=" . attr($_GET['mode']);
}
```

Comment: Make sure the variable is assigned inside the (same) iframe. Yet, you posted code for iframe; where's the one for DIV? It's the same thing `<div><?php $frame1url = "URL"; echo $frame1url; ?></div>`

Comment: What do you mean by use ? Your example already shows how to embed a PHP variable in some HTML code :)

Comment: You need to describe your issue a little better. It seems that you have already answered your question within your question with the info you have given us.

Comment: i want to remove the frame and use the div in place of it. echoing variable in div is not working likewise in frame.

Comment: It'll probably be easier if you used sessions.

Comment: Fred -ii- i have updated the code please suggest me if any solutions for removing frame and in place of it div working similarly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div style="<?php echo $yourDataStyle; ?>"><?php echo $yourData; ?></div>
<iframe src="<?php echo $frame1url; ?>" name="RTop" scrolling="auto" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Jailout your idea is pretty similar to what is already being used used, but i need the to be changed to div, where $frame1url is required to work the way it was working in frame..any idea how?

Comment: i am updating the php for echo variable.